# "TypeError: Unknown parameter type: <class 'dict_values'>"

Tags: python, dictionary, input, theano

I am using this code: "https://github.com/LouisFoucard/MC_DCNN/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/MultiChannel_DeepConvNet-checkpoint.ipynb"

When I run the code, I get the error that:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_values' and 'list'

This error is related to this line of the code:

```
train = theano.function(inps.values()+[target_values],cost, updates=updates)
```

I changed this line to:

```
train = theano.function(inputs=[inps.values(), target_values], outputs=cost, updates=updates)
```

This time I get the error that:

> TypeError: Unknown parameter type:

This seems that Theano.function does not accept Dictionary.values as inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask], include the relevant parts of your [MCVE] directly in the question, and make sure the formatting looks pleasant.

Comment: See the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for how to format your code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to run some python 2 code in python 3, 
where `dict.values` returns a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)

The solution is quite simple - just wrap your `dict.values` in a `list`:

```
train = theano.function(list(inps.values())+[target_values], cost, updates=updates)
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your help