# "torch.relu_(input) unknown parameter type" from pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory, pose-estimation

I am trying to run this [3D pose estimation repo](https://github.com/ultravideo/Stereo-3D-Pose-Estimation) in Google Colab on a GPU, but after doing all of the steps and putting in my own left/right cam vids, I get this error in Colab:

```
infering thread started
1 1
: cannot connect to X server 
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/content/Stereo-3D-Pose-Estimation/poseinferscheduler.py", line 59, in infer_pose_loop
    l_pose_t = infer_fast(self.net, l_img, height, self.stride, self.upsample_ratio, self.cpu)
  File "/content/Stereo-3D-Pose-Estimation/pose3dmodules.py", line 47, in infer_fast
    stages_output = net(tensor_img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/Stereo-3D-Pose-Estimation/models/with_mobilenet.py", line 115, in forward
    backbone_features = self.model(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py", line 102, in forward
    return F.relu(input, inplace=self.inplace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1296, in relu
    result = torch.relu_(input)
RuntimeError: unknown parameter type
```

I am a bit confused as to why I am seeing it, I have already installed all necessary prerequisites; also can't interpret what it means either.

Answer (score 1):

Since the traceback happens in the pytorch library, I checked the code there on the pytorch github.

What the error means is that you are calling an inplace activation function in torch.relu_ to some object called input. However, what is happening is that the type of input is not recognized by the torch backend which is why it is a runtime error.

Therefore, I would suggest to print out input and also run

```
type(input)
```

to find out what object input represents and what that variable is. As a further reference, this is the particular script that Pytorch runs in the backend that leads it to throw an unknown parameter type error. From a quick look, it seems to be a switch statement that confirms if a value falls into a list of types. If it is not in the list of types, then it will run the default block which throws unknown parameter type error.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/aacc722aeca3de1aedd35adb41e6f8149bd656cd/torch/csrc/utils/python_arg_parser.cpp#L518-L541

## EDIT:

If type(input) returns a torch.tensor then it is probably an issue with the version of python you are using. I know you said you have the prerequisites but I think it would be good to double check if you have python 3.6, and maybe but less preferably python 3.5 or 3.7. These are the python versions that work with the repo you just sent me.

You can find the python version on your collab by typing
`!python --version` on one of cells. Make sure that it returns a correct version supported by the software you are running. This error might come from the fact that instead of torch, python itself is expressing this error in its backend.

I found this stackoverflow useful as it shows how some code was unable to recognize a built in type dictionary in python: ["TypeError: Unknown parameter type: <class 'dict_values'>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657686/typeerror-unknown-parameter-type-class-dict-values)
The solution to this was to check python versions.

Sarthak

Comment: I tried printing type, and I am getting what I think is correct: ```<class 'torch.Tensor'>```